# Adding texture on the background of TcxGrid cell?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I can color background of TcxGrid cell with code `ACanvas.Brush.Color:=Color` in `OnCustomDrawCell`. Is it possible to add texture in this event handler? I can not use custom painting of the cell, because lot of other configuration occurs here (font color, style, etc). So - should I use Brush properties somehow?

Comment: With the reservation that I never used `TcxGrid` I'm pretty confident you can use `Vcl.Graphics.TBrush` properties. The interesting ones might be `Style: TBrushStyle` and `Bitmap: TBitmap`. Bitmap should be quite clear, `Vcl.Graphics.TBrushStyle` documents what patterns you can use.

Comment: I'd try using cxStyles. E.g. there's a TcxStyle.Bitmap property that you might be able to use.